# Elixir: Latency between creation and registry of a GenServer in distributed Horde and calling its API

Tags: elixir, distributed-computing

I'm using Horde 0.8.3 to manage the distributed registry and supervisor of an Elixir application. The application creates `UserAgent`-s (UA for short) that are implemented as `GenServer`-s. Each UA represents a user connected to the application. UAs are created  with `Horde.DynamicSupervisor.start_child(MyApi.DSup, {MyApi.UserAgent, user})`. In the same function where the UA is created, the application calls a UA client API, say `UserAgent.ping(ua_id)` (the nature of this API is not important here). `ping(...)` uses `via_tuple` to find the `pid` of the UA in the registry and sends it a `:ping` message.

The application is started on two nodes, say N1 and N2. Suppose `start_child(...)` and `ping()...` execute on N1 while the UA had been created on N2. When `ping(...)` is called in these conditions, most of the time it doesn't find the UA in the Horde registry. I did some experiments and found the UA becomes available (in Horde) after about 150ms to 350ms, 250ms on average.

Obviously that time is needed for Horde machinery (deltaCRDT) to have the data dispatched on all nodes of the cluster. That dispatch is done asynchronously in the background.

1. 250ms on average seems a bit long for an app running on the one physical server (no network latency expected) with 12 cores and while the registry is empty. Is this a *normal* latency or should we dig a bit more to see if there is an issue ?
2. I would have thought the `Horde.DynamicSupervisor.start_child(...)` was synchronous, that is it returns only once all dispatching was done, as it is supposed to have *the same behavior as the standard `DynamicSupervisor`*. Is this assumtion correct and is there a way to have have a synchronous call ?
3. I ended by implementing the function `get_pid(id, ...)` below that I call to get the `pid` of a UA. Is this really a good solution ?

   ```
   def get_pid(_id, _wait, waited, max_wait) when waited > max_wait, do: :error

   def get_pid(id, wait, waited, max_wait) do
     Logger.debug("get_pid(#{id}, wait=#{wait}, waited=#{waited}, max_wait=#{max_wait})")
     case Horde.Registry.lookup(via_tuple(id)) do  [
       {pid, _}] ->
         Logger.debug("\t-> got pid=#{inspect pid}")
         pid
       [] ->
         Logger.debug("\t-> got []. Going for a nap for #{wait}ms")
         Process.sleep(wait)
         get_pid(id, wait*2, waited+wait, max_wait)
     end
   end
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I actually opened a case on [github](https://github.com/derekkraan/horde/issues/223) and got the confirmation from the author that this is a normal behavior. The 250ms or so latency can be adjusted with *(...) `sync_interval` by passing the `:delta_crdt_options` option (...)*.